# How to delete namespace in Google Cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a couple of Google App Engine versions in a project, and I use its Datastore. Each version creates a namespace on Datastore, where I have created some entities within a couple of kinds.

Now I've deleted some of the versions, and I want to delete their stuff on Datastore. I've deleted the entities, then the referred kinds had disappeared, but I can't find a way to delete the namespaces.

How can I delete a namespace in Google Cloud Datastore?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each namespace stores a set of system kinds eg. statistics: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/stats 
Those are reculculated every 48h, and deleted if there are no more user data in that namespace. At that time namespace should disappear from your Datastore as well.

Comment: I checked them now, and they did disappear. Thank you very much! I had to ask here as I couldn't find that info around.

Comment: Is there no way to delete the whole namespace with all its entities with a single command? Do I need to delete all the data in the namespace "manually"?